# Killing a process with cron as soon as it starts

Tags: linux, cron

I want to stop dropbox from running as soon as I log into my account. Now I know I could do this simply by going to `Startup Applications` and disabling dropbox. But I was wondering if there is a cron-ish way of doing it or is cron not supposed to be used for stuff like these?

Currently I have this in my crontab

```
@reboot pkill dropbox
```

But this doesn't work, because I guess dropbox isn't running when this cron-job runs.

Comment: Sounds like you simply want to stop dropbox from running.  Why not just change the permissions on the binary so that it is not executable?

Comment: @mdpc . I could do that too, yes. Or as I said, going to Startup Applications and disabling dropbox would work too. But just out of curiosity, I was wondering if it could be done via cron. ;)

Comment: Or if you do not even want the application, simply uninstall it!

Comment: @mdpc I guess 99 ways to do it but cron ain't one? :P

Comment: Seems very convoluted at best, why not use the easiest approach instead or a rube goldberg type of solution.

Comment: Just out of curiosity @mdpc. I guess I want to understand cron better. Because my initial solution for this was to use cron. But since cron isn't working here, I am curious as to when exactly is cron useful.

Comment: @zack "When exactly cron is useful" is a different question. Please post it as a separate question. (Though be careful how you phrase it so it doesn't end up too broad or primarily opinion-based. Consider [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@reboot` entry is there for doing things after each reboot. That is not what you want.

Cron is not the right tool for this, as it starts something at a specific time and it has no clue about you being logged in or being in the process of logged in. At most a cron job run every minute could look if you are logged in and then take action.

It is better to try and kill dropbox (using `pkill` e.g.) with a Startup application.